# Использование Pool.map(function, args)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть функция вида:

```py
result, number = calculate(model, inputdata, outputdata, outputdatatype, log):
...
```

которая позволяет работать с одним входным файлом:

```
(inputdata = example.wav; outputdata = example.txt, outputdatatype = txt, log = INFO)
```

-несколько аргументов.
Но когда файлов много мне посоветовали использовать Pool.map:

```py
p = Pool(4)
result, number = p.starmap(calculate, [(example1.wav, example1.txt, txt, INFO), (example2.wav, example2.txt, txt, INFO), ..., (example_N.wav, example_N.txt, txt, INFO)])
```

но это не работает, подскажите как туда передать эти аргументы правильно

Comment: А `model` вы не передаёте?

Comment: передаю, забыл добавить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых вы не передаёте первый аргумент `model`. Во-вторых вы должны проитерироваться по результатам, их же у вас будет столько, сколько раз вы по факту будете вызывать функцию с разными аргументами. И в-третьих нужно закрыть `Pool`, лучше с помощью контекстного менеджера. Как-то так:

```py
with Pool(4) as p:
    for result, number in p.starmap(calculate, [(model, example1.wav, example1.txt, txt, INFO), (model, example2.wav, example2.txt, txt, INFO), ..., (model, example_N.wav, example_N.txt, txt, INFO)]):
        print(result, number)
```

Comment: спасибо, заработало, нужен был цикл.